# SIGSTP error in lead game problem of codechef. TLG problem

Tags: c++, vector

```
`
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    vector<int>v1, v2;
    v1.push_back(0);
    v2.push_back(0);
    while (t--)
    {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a > b)
            v1.push_back(a - b);
        else
            v2.push_back(b - a);
    }
    int m1, m2;
    if (v1.size() > 1)

        m1 = *max_element(v1.begin(), v1.end());
    else
        m1 = 0;
    if (v2.size() > 1)
        m2 = *max_element(v2.begin(), v2.end());
    else
        m2 = 0;
    if (m1 > m2)
        cout << "1" << " " << m1;
    else
        cout << "2" << " " << m2;
}
`
```

this is lead game question in codechef but I am getting SIGSTP  error while running code. I am not getting how to overcome this. I have spend my a plenty of time. Can someone help me to getting rid of this problem.I am new in the competitive programming. Please suggest me some resources or lectures on youtube to do better.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Hard to see why that code would crash. Do you know what input it crashes on? Do you have a link to the question?

Comment: sometimes a non-zero return value in `main()` can cause this error. if that's the case, adding `return 0` at the end of `main()` should solve the issue.

Comment: which compiler did you choose while submitting the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting this code didn't got me SIGSTP but I got Wrong Answer verdict. This is due to the fact that you are not checking the cumulative scores of the players but directly comparing the current scores and pushing them in the vectors accordingly. You can maintain two variables to store the cumulative scores of the players and then check that which player has the current lead. Try the following solution:

```
int main() 
{
    
    int rounds;
    cin >> rounds ; 
    int lead = 0 ;
        int player = 0;
    int cs1 = 0 , cs2 = 0 ;
    while(rounds--){
        int p1 , p2 ;
        cin >> p1 >> p2 ;
        cs1+=p1;
        cs2+=p2;
        if(cs1 > cs2 && lead < (cs1 - cs2) ){
            lead = cs1 - cs2 ;
            player = 1;
            
        }
        else if(cs2 > cs1 && lead < (cs2 - cs1))
        {
            lead = cs2 - cs1 ;
            player = 2;
        
        }
        
    }
    cout << player << " " << lead << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    // your code goes here
     int n;
   cin>>n;
   int max=0,player=1;
   int cs1=0,cs2=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
        int si,ti;
        cin>>si>>ti;
        cs1=cs1+si;
        cs2=cs2+ti;
        if(abs(cs1-cs2)>max)
        {
            max=abs(cs1-cs2);
            if(cs1>cs2)
            player=1;
            else
            player=2;
        }
   
   
   }
   cout<<player<<" "<<max<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Ive provided an alternate approach to the TLG problem. When you get the input compute the cumulative scores then and there itself and later assign the difference to the player who has higher cumulative score.Hope this helps!

Comment: But till now I haven't got the corner cases in my program where it is failed?